# How to uninstall Universal Media Server

Tags: uninstall

I would like to uninstall the Universal Media Server, but can't find on it's site a how to. I am new to Ubuntu 14.04LTS, new to Ubuntu period as well as old (in age appr. 72yo). So have pity on me and tell me how to do it.
Thank you for replying.

Edit: I downloaded a compressed file. Can't remember what kind. But, after I had "installed" it, no icon would come up to launch it. Found out how to get an icon to launch it. Thinking about it it seemed that it executes from the directory I unpacked it to. 
Deleted the directory and looked for configuration files with UMS in the name and deleted them. So it looked like it is gone. Hopefully it did not leave any remnants.
Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Sorry, in the post it should say Server instead of Player, but can't find one on it's site

Comment: You can [edit] your posts.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how did you install it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Universal Media Server is a Java based application that is distributed as a Java executable jar file, among others (folders, configuration). Installing it only means that you have to unzip the downloaded distribution package file in a folder.

The distribution includes a UMS.sh file that starts the JVM with the appropriate parameters. This is the way to start and use the Universal Media Server.

The java application is using by default as working directory the folder where the downloaded file has been unzipped. So, it's good you deleted that.

Furthermore, the application creates a configuration folder under `~/.config/UMS`. So, you have to delete this also: `rm -r ~/.config/UMS`.